# Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Here is my entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "Task")
class TaskEntity {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ID")
    var id: Long = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Title")
    lateinit var title: String
}
```

I added this class to my database class entity list, while trying to check I'm getting following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: Task(com.idesign.iplacenotes.controller.database.room.entity.TaskEntity).
 Expected:
TableInfo{name='Task', columns={Title=Column{name='Title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ID=Column{name='ID', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
 Found:
TableInfo{name='Task', columns={}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

Might be very silli mistake, but I don't know what I have missed.

Here is the Migration code,

```
private val MIGRATION_35_36 = object : Migration(35, 36) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `Task` (`ID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `Title` TEXT NOT NULL)")
            }
        }
```

Here I'm initializing my database

```
fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_35_36)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build()
    }
    return instance as AppDatabase
}
```

Comment: You need to add Room database migration support OR If you added new field in your existing app then you must uninstall older version and install new version in same mobile device

Comment: @MD, I'm getting this error while newly installing it...

Comment: Can you show me how you init Room database ?

Comment: @MD I have updated the post.

Comment: @MD, Upto version 35 I used SQLiteOpenHelper, Is that the cause for this problem?

Comment: The only way that I can replicate the issue is to not include the table create (i.e. `database.execSQL(..........`). That results in a the same expected not found, i.e. con columns.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @NazmulHasan No, I gone with new database.